# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'

Tags: vb.net, casting

When clicking on required item in a populated List view following error occurs when clicking frm.showdialog:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'

```
Private Sub mnuView_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuView.Click
    Dim frm As New frmAllView
    tsStatus.Text = ""
    FormChange(bFormChanged)
    Me.Hide()
    If Not dataMgr.MTDatabase Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a record to continue", "No records")
        Me.Show()
    Else
        frm.ShowDialog()  '//--- **error occurs here** ---
        If frm.lvwDisplay.SelectedIndices.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            iID = CInt(frm.lvwDisplay.SelectedItems(0).Index)
            NoRecords()
            dataMgr.FindOneName(iID, nc)
            FillBoxes()

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Obviously, I do not know how to enter my code.

Comment: intend a minimum of four spaces or use STRG+K

Comment: You will need to check your handlers on that form. I'm guessing you have created one?

Comment: Like @Bugs says one of your event handlers in the `frmAllView` appears to have an incorrect signature (perhaps the `Load` event since the error is thrown right on `ShowDialog()`?). Check every event handler's type of the `e` parameter and make sure that only `KeyPress` handlers use the type `KeyPressEventArgs`.